# How to add small header (textblock) near the top left corner of the Image?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, textblock, stackpanel

I've got an app, which shows preview of documentation, using thumbnails. 
What I need, is to have a small header (text) near each thumbnail of Image.
The header should be to the left from the image, on the top, how is shown on the picture. I managed to add textblock with number of page on the image. 
Please, give your advices. The image thumbnails are generated dynamically in the code behind. Here is part of code behind. I managed to achieve my purpose, but I want to find more elegant solution.

[image]

```
RowDefinitionCollection rd = gridPreview.RowDefinitions;
ColumnDefinitionCollection cd =gridPreview.ColumnDefinitions;

int columnAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(gridPreviewWidth / GetThumbnailSizes(tiffImageList).Item2));
gridPreviewHeight = ((tiffImageList.Count / columnAmount) + 1) * GetThumbnailSizes(tiffImageList).Item1 + 100;

for (int i = 0; i < (tiffImageList.Count / columnAmount) + 1; i++)
{
    rd.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
    for (int j = 0; j < columnAmount; j++)
    {
        cd.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
    }
}

foreach (var tiffImage in tiffImageList)
{
    if (columnIndex == columnAmount)
    {
        columnIndex = 0;
        rowIndex++;
    }


    Image imagePreviewItem = new Image();
    imagePreviewItem.Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 20, 20);
    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
    textBlock.Margin = new Thickness(-370,0,0,0);
    textBlock.Text = $"{tiffImage.index.ToString()}"; // Header text

    RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(imagePreviewItem, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
    imagePreviewItem.Name = $"Image{tiffImage.index.ToString()}";


    imagePreviewItem.Source = tiffImage.image.Thumbnail;

    StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
    stackPanel.Width = imagePreviewItem.Width + 50;
    stackPanel.Height = imagePreviewItem.Height + 50;
    stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
    stackPanel.Children.Add(imagePreviewItem);

    Border border = new Border();
    border.BorderBrush = Brushes.LightGray;
    border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
    Thickness margin = border.Margin;
    border.Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 20, 20); ;
    border.Child = stackPanel;
    Grid.SetColumn(border, columnIndex);
    Grid.SetRow(border, rowIndex);

    gridPreview.Children.Add(border);
}
```

Comment: Please don't construct UI in code. In WPF, you are supposed to do this in a declarative way, using XAML.

Comment: For showing a collection of elements like e.g. a collection if images, use an ItemsControl (or a subclass like ListBox). Create the UI for an individual item in a DataTemplate that is used as the ItemTemplate of the ItemsControl. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: Thanks for your advices, I'm quite new to WPF and C#, so I create horrible coding. I'll improve my skills with your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of adding `textBlock` with number into `stackPanel`, add it into `gridPreview` on top of `border` in the top left corner:

```
foreach (var tiffImage in tiffImageList)
{
    if (columnIndex == columnAmount)
    {
        columnIndex = 0;
        rowIndex++;
    }

    Image imagePreviewItem = new Image();
    imagePreviewItem.Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 20, 20);
    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
    textBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    textBlock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    textBlock.Margin = new Thickness(40, 40, 40, 40);
    textBlock.Text = $"{tiffImage.index.ToString()}"; // Header text

    RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(imagePreviewItem, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
    imagePreviewItem.Name = $"Image{tiffImage.index.ToString()}";
    imagePreviewItem.Source = tiffImage.image.Thumbnail;

    StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
    stackPanel.Width = imagePreviewItem.Width + 50;
    stackPanel.Height = imagePreviewItem.Height + 50;
    stackPanel.Children.Add(imagePreviewItem);

    Border border = new Border();
    border.BorderBrush = Brushes.LightGray;
    border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
    Thickness margin = border.Margin;
    border.Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 20, 20);
    border.Child = stackPanel;
    Grid.SetColumn(border, columnIndex);
    Grid.SetRow(border, rowIndex);

    Grid.SetColumn(textBlock, columnIndex);
    Grid.SetRow(textBlock, rowIndex);

    gridPreview.Children.Add(border);
    gridPreview.Children.Add(textBlock);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, certainly it helped. At first it didn't work, but I changed textBlock.Margin = new Thickness(-1, 20, 40, 40);
and it worked. 
Maybe, this is not elegant and correct solution, but, at least, it works.